# Explanation of declaring a foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've been given some relations and I have to declare the foreign keys using the SQL syntax. I have done it but I am unsure why it works or how to explain it so that I can understand it better.

The relation is:

> PRIVATE_PATIENT(patient, consultant)

and the foreign keys i have declared are:

> FOREIGN KEY (patient) REFERENCE Patient (Patient)
>
> FOREIGN KEY (consultant) REFERENCE Consultants (consultant)

I am not sure whether these declarations are correct but please could someone explain to me either a process to declare a foreign key or just a justified way of explaining the foreign keys I have.

Comment: `alter table private_patient add constraint fk_private_patient_patient foreign key . . . `.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not altering tho, I am simply declaring separately to the table to practice writing in SQL syntax, but am not sure if that syntax is corrent